# Node 8 vs 11 Timezone is different

Tags: javascript, node.js

Running a simple `new Date().toString()`. On Node 11, You get something like

```
'Fri May 10 2019 10:44:44 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)'
```

While on Node 8 you get

```
'Fri May 10 2019 10:44:44 GMT-0700 (PDT)'
```

Note the different in timezone abbreviation. Why is that? And how can you force `toString()` to always return the zone in the abbreviation?

Comment: I can't seem to find any documentation on Date objects in the node docs, and the MDN only has a non-version documentation of the date object. Interesting

Comment: @SterlingArcher that's because the Date object is not part of the Node.js API, it's provided by V8, so you won't see anything in the Node docs.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande that makes sense. I also learned that there's also reliance in the Intl spec as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stolen answer from @ssube who was too lazy to log in and post.

> the whole `Intl` object and default formats were introduced between those two versions, which may have become the new default for `Date` as well.

After some digging on my own, and reading some of the [Intl spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/2.0/#sec-time-zone-names):

> The ECMAScript 2015 Internationalization API Specification identifies time zones using the Zone and Link names of the IANA Time Zone Database. Their canonical form is the corresponding Zone name in the casing used in the IANA Time Zone Database.

As to how to revert back to an abbreviated timezone, I am seeing that there are several github repos that suggest using regex, others using an abbreviation Map, or even Ben Nadel who uses some regex to process the short timezone or long timezone, as seen in his blog [here](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3471-timezone-in-date-totimestring-is-not-always-an-abbreviation-in-javascript.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like JavaScript leaves this up to the implementer. Based on the below [GitHub Issue for ECMA262](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/845), there are known differences between the ways UNIX & Windows handle the timezone value.

> Across multiple JS implementations, it seems that Date.prototype.toString writes the timezone (in parens) in a long, locale-dependent form on Windows, but in a short form (2-4 letters) from the tz database on Unix-based OSes. More details in the V8 bug tracker.
>
> The spec is really light on details for Date.prototype.toString:
>
> > Return an implementation-dependent String value that represents tv as a date and time in the current time zone using a convenient, human-readable form.
>
> Does anyone have a good memory of why this is the definition? Looks like it goes all the way back to ES1.
>
> Fortunately, it seems that, at this point, implementations have converged on something that's almost always the same, with the exception of the timezone string.
>
> For the timezone string, would it be a good idea to pick one of the two alternatives and standardize it across all platforms? Does anyone have evidence one way or the other whether either of the two is likely to be more web-compatible, or whether we need to preserve the variation?

Additionally, it looks like there is still active discussion in the [V8 Issues for `Date.prototype.toString()` normalization](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=6076).

Going through the NodeJS there doesn't seem to be an explicit mention of this in their change logs for v10+.

#### Update

After digging through V8 commits, it looks like there is a new Timezone Names Cache implemented for performance in V8 when using `Date.prototype.toString()`. Based on the below excerpt from the message for [this commit](https://github.com/v8/v8/commit/7e87f446258700aaa04d8760271effba9805e89b), it seems like this change is why there is a difference between Node v8 & Node v11

> To speed up Date.prototype.toString(), this patch adds a cache in the
>   DateCache for the string short name representing the time zone.
>   Because time zones in a particular location just have two short names
>   (for DST and standard time), and the DateCache already understands
>   whether a time is in DST or not, it is possible to keep the result of
>   OS::LocalTimezone around and select between the two based on whether
>   the time is DST or not.
>
> In local microbenchmarks (calling Date.prototype.toString() in a
>   loop), I observed a 6-10% speedup with this patch. In the browser, the
>   speedup may be even greater as the system call needs to do some extra
>   work to break out of the sandbox. I don't think the microbenchmark is
>   extremely unrealistic; in any real program which calls
>   Date.prototype.toString() multiple times, the cache should hit almost
>   all of the time, as time zone changes are rare.
>
> The proximate motivation for this patch was to enable ICU as a backend
>   for timezone information, which is drafted at
>   https://codereview.chromium.org/2724373002/ The ICU implementation of
>   OS::LocalTimezone is even slower than the system call one, but this
>   patch makes their performance indistinguishable on the microbenchmark.
>
> In the tz database, many timezones actually do have a number of
>   different historical names. For example, America/Anchorage went
>   through a number of changes, from AST to AHST to YST to AKST. However,
>   both ICU and the Linux OS interfaces just report the modern timezone
>   name in tests for the appropriate timezone name, even for historical
>   times. I can see why this would be:
>   - For ICU, CLDR only has two short names in the data file: the one for   dst and non-dst
>   - For Linux, the timezone names do seem to make it into the   /etc/localtime file. However, glibc assumes there are only two
>   relevant   names and selects between them, as you can see in its
>   implementation   of localtime_r:
>   http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~vcs-imports/glibc/master/view/head:/time/tzset.c#L573
>   So, this cache should be valid until we switch to a more accurate
>   source of short timezone names.

Comment: I ran both from my personal Mac computer. I just installed different versions of Node.

Comment: @Kousha, looks like the change made in this [v8 commit](https://github.com/v8/v8/commit/7e87f446258700aaa04d8760271effba9805e89b) is what changed the naming of the Timezone.